# Excel VBA Macro Debugging - Application/Object-defined error (error 1004)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on debugging a macro for a colleague of mine and I was not the original writer of the code.  That being said, the issue was created when excel updated, causing the macro to become defective - Application-defined or Object-defined error (ERROR '1004')

Here is a look at the specific portion of code:

Next n_counter

```
'calculate aggregated results
For counter_res = 1 To 7
    'insert variance of null distribution
        Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 2).Value = _
        Worksheets("L_S_2008").Cells(2 + counter_res, no_anchors).Value
    'mean values of agreement index
        Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 3).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(3, 18 + counter_res), _
        Cells(5000, 18 + counter_res)))
    'SD of agreement index
        Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 4).Value = _
        (WorksheetFunction.Var(Range(Cells(3, 18 + counter_res), _
        Cells(5000, 18 + counter_res)))) ^ 0.5
    'P25 of agreement index
        Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 6).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range(Cells(3, 18 + counter_res), _
        Cells(5000, 18 + counter_res)), 0.25)
    'Median (P50) of agreement index
        Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 7).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range(Cells(3, 18 + counter_res), _
        Cells(5000, 18 + counter_res)), 0.5)
    'P25 of agreement index
        Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 8).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range(Cells(3, 18 + counter_res), _
        Cells(5000, 18 + counter_res)), 0.75)
```

Debugging returned the very first line of code

```
[Worksheets("results").Cells(22 + counter_res, 2).Value = Worksheets("L_S_2008").Cells(2 + counter_res, no_anchors).Value]
```

as the source of the error.

If anyone has some feedback or advice, I would be greatly honored. Thank you in advance for taking a look at the problem, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Either the sheets are named incorrectly, or the variable no_anchors hasn't got a valid value for a column. When you debug, what value does no_anchors have...? If 0, that's the problem.  Can't have a cell with a column value < 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can tighten up that code a lot by removing all of the repetition - that might help with debugging.

Possible causes of your current problem would be a bad value in `no_anchors` as noted by smackenzie, or maybe that the input sheet used for your calculations isn't the one you expect (since it's not explicitly specified)

```
Dim rngCalc As Range, wsf As WorksheetFunction
Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction


'calculate aggregated results
For counter_res = 1 To 7

    'What sheet is this intended to reference?
    'By default it will be the ActiveSheet unless specified
    Set rngCalc = Range(Cells(3, 18 + counter_res), _
                        Cells(5000, 18 + counter_res))

    With Worksheets("results").Rows(22 + counter_res)

        .Cells(2).Value = Worksheets("L_S_2008").Cells(2 + counter_res, _
                            no_anchors).Value           'variance

        .Cells(3).Value = wsf.Average(rngCalc)          'Mean
        .Cells(4).Value = wsf.Var(rngCalc) ^ 0.5        'SD
        .Cells(6).Value = wsf.Percentile(rngCalc, 0.25) 'P25
        .Cells(7).Value = wsf.Percentile(rngCalc, 0.5)  'Median(P50)
        .Cells(8).Value = wsf.Percentile(rngCalc, 0.75) 'P75

    End With

Next counter_res
```